# does civix need a mysql install?

Tags: civix

I would use civix for coding a scheduled task that updates a customed field. I could generate an extension skeletton with the "civix generate:module" command, but fail to use "civix generate:api" for generating an api to be scheduled.

My CiviCRM is embedded in Drupal and hosted by Google cloud. I have a local copy of the civicrm part of my site, but without the mysql database. When executing the civix generate:api command, I get an error that seems coming from mysql : Initialization Error - DB error : extension not found.

Is mysql mandatory for having "civix generate:api" working ?
How can I avoid my civicrm copy to launch mysql ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: solved by a "extension=php_mysql.dll" directive in the php.ini file.
But remains an "Initialization Error" during the call "Services::api3()".

Answer (score 1):

Although not clearly stated in the civix documentation, a full running mysql database is mandatory with the CiviCRM application for an api generation.
A good reason for me to have an online clone of my site for testing.